# Stability conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences

Below is a problem about stability conditions that I have been struggling with it during an exam:

> Find the stability conditions for
>
> $$A\left ( \frac{\partial^2 u(x,\, y,\,t)}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2 u(x,\,y,\,t)}{\partial y^2} \right ) = \frac{\partial^2 u(x,\,t)}{\partial t^2}$$
>
> $$0 \leq x \leq x_f , \; 0 \leq y \leq y_f ,\; 0 \leq t \leq T$$

Please help me with your ideas, Thanks in advance.

Comment: What to you mean by stability conditions? Stability of zero solution? Of some other solution? Stability of numerical scheme that solves the numerical approximation of your equation?

Comment: you may help this link http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/EquilibriumSolutions.aspx

Comment: @TZakrevskiy : Yes, I'm looking for stability conditions of zero solution.